# Estimating posterior of proportion of positives in population from per-observation probabilities

Tags: bayesian, proportion, posterior, pymc, credible-interval

I have a sample from some population of 0s and 1s and need to estimate the posterior of the proportion of 1s in this population. But the catch is: for each observation in the sample I only have probabilities of the observation being positive.

If I had true labels for each observation I would just go with $ Beta(1+num\_positive, 1+num\_negative) $ taking $ Beta(1, 1) $ as prior. But in my case where I have probabilities what should the solution be?

One solution I can think of is $ Beta(1+\sum_i p_i, 1 + n - \sum_i p_i) $ where $n$ is sample size and $p_i$ are per observation probabilities. Basically taking the expectations of the numbers of positives and negatives.

Am I thinking in the right direction?

The practical reason for this: the probabilities come from a perfectly calibrated binary classifier outputs on an unlabeled dataset and I need to estimate credible interval of the proportion of positives in this dataset.

Also what about the case where instead of perfectly calibrated probabilities they themselves are random variables with certain distribution (let's say I perform Bayesian Platt scaling and have posterior of A and B parameters)?

Comment: It rather depends on why you think the probability of an observation being $1$ is $p_i$.  If you calculated it on the basis of the prior $Beta(1,1)$, then the predicted probability of each would be $p_i=\frac12$ and none of this information would be useful in updating the prior to give a new posterior distribution as you have nothing new to use.  In conventional Bayesian updating, you want to use the likelihood given the observations, uncontaminated by the prior: What would the likelihood be in your case?

Comment: @Henry not sure I follow, sorry. Let's say that I have 2000 observations with probabilities $p_i=0.5$ - that would make me pretty certain that the actual proportion of positives in the population is equal to 0.5 since I would expect around the same number of positives and negatives. What you are describing I think is uniform [0, 1] distribution for each per-observation probability, that will in fact give us no information. But in my first case you can assume that probabilities are certain and their PDF looks like $f(x)=\delta(x-p_i)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: My point was that if you had a system where you chose a random variable $Q_i \sim U[0,1]$ and then had a random variable $X_i \sim Bernoulli(Q_i)$ then you can say the marginal distribution of $X_i$ has $\mathbb P(X_i=1)=\mathbb E[Q_i]=\frac12$.  It might then be difficult to avoid saying $p_i =\frac12$ despite the uncertainty in $Q_i$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant binary probability estimator instead of binary classifier as you didn't classify the observations.  It's good that the probability estimator is well calibrated.  The estimated probabilities will still have uncertainties though, since the sample size used to estimate them is not $\infty$.  For a full Bayesian solution you'd need to know these uncertainties.  That would give rise to a posterior distribution for each probability.

Were a full Bayesian method to be used in estimating the probabilities from the beginning (e.g., Bayesian binary logistic regression), with MCMC used to draw samples from the probabilities' posterior distributions, you could get your final answer quite easily using the following steps:

1. Draw one posterior sample for each of $n$ probabilities
2. Sum these to get a posterior sample of the number of positives
3. Divide by $n$ to get a posterior sample of the fraction of positives
4. Repeat for $m$ posterior draws where $m$ is several thousand
5. Compute the empirical CDF or kernel density estimator from the $m$ samples of the fraction of positives to get the posterior distribution of interest

If the risk model development sample is different from the sample or population to which you want to apply the probability estimates, in a logistic regression setting you would do the following.

1. The posterior draws would be on the $\hat{\beta}$ from the logistic model used to estimate the probabilities
2. The probability estimates would plug in different $X$ predictor values than those occurring in the training sample

Comment: Thanks! But am I correct that your method produces posterior of proportion of positivies in the sample rather than in the population?

Comment: The initial method, yes.  Use the second method to get an out-of-sample estimate.